# How to compare multiple keys with distinctUntilKeyChanged?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm still learning rxjs, and I'm a little stuck on how to write a custom compare function for the operator distinctUntilChanged.

I looked into using distinctUntilKeyChanged, which works great for a single key...But I have two keys that I need to compare.

It seems I might need to incorprate the scan operator to compare the current value emitted to the last value emitted....?

Ok, here is my code. I'm streaming map center changes from google maps. I don't need the map center GeoLocation to be very precise, so I'm rounding off most of the decimals returned by google maps.

```
searchStream$
  .map((value)=>{
  return {
    lat: round(value[1].lat, 1),
    lng: round(value[1].lng, 1)
  }
}).distinctUntilKeyChanged('lat')
  .do((position)=>{console.log(position)})
  .subscribe((position)=>{ this._store.dispatch(new QueryUpdateGeoPositionAPIAction({latitude: position.lat, longitude: position.lng})) });
```

So back to my question, **how can I compare both properties(lat & lng) to ensure that it's only emitting values when either one of the values change?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is an example in the docs: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged

Answer (score 3):

*From the RxJS section  of the [`distinct` documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html):*

> In RxJS, the distinct operator has two optional parameters:
>
> 1. a function that accepts an item emitted by the source Observable and returns a key which will be used instead of the item itself when comparing two items for distinctness
> 2. a function that accepts two items (or two keys) and compares them for distinctness, returning `false` if they are distinct (an equality function is the default if you do not supply your own function here)

So it looks to me (with no testing) that you could simply pass something like

```
(a, b) => a.lat === b.lat && a.lon === b.lon
```

I'm not sure about RxJS conventions to know how you should pass this (second optional) parameter.

Comment: This is correct..except for the fact that I wanted to check the previous emitted value to the current value. For this, I needed distinctUntilChanged operator..not just the distinct operator. But you code example works great. Thank you...if you switch up your answer to the correct operator, I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I don't know if there is separate documentation for `distinctUntilChanged`.  It seems that it is simply embedded in the `distinct` documentation page.  I don't have much experience with RxJS, but so far, I find their documentation organization fairly frustrating.

Comment: `!keys.some(key => old[key] !== current[key])`

This would be more efficient. no need to compare every property when you can return as soon as one changed. It is also more readable

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and this situation isn't covered by the docs.

this will add the `.distinctUntilKeysChanged` operator. just pass it any keys to "watch" for

```js
const {
  Observable,
  Subject
} = Rx;

Observable.prototype.distinctUntilKeysChanged = function(...keys) {
  return this.distinctUntilChanged((old, current) =>
    // if no value changed,
    // the array will only have true values,
    // includes(false) will be false,
    // convert to oposite (!),
    // returns true;
    // => true = do nothing

    // if any value changed,
    // the array will include some false,
    // includes(false) will be true,
    // convert to oposite (!),
    // returns false;
    // => false = emit

    !keys
    .map(key => old[key] === current[key]) // converts to array of boolean
    .includes(false) // if any value changed
  );
};

const stream = new Subject();

stream
  .distinctUntilKeysChanged('prop', 'prop2')
  .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 42,
  prop2: 54,
});

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 54,
});

// shouldn't log because neither prop nor prop2 changed
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 54,
});

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 5454665654645,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

the only downside to this is that you can't specify a custom comparison function. if you do want to specify one you could use this instead (which is more similar to the implementation of `.distinctUntilKeyChanged` where the first argument is the key and the second is the comparison function). Notice that this one takes an array of keys where the first one took the keys as separate arguments

```js
const {
  Observable,
  Subject
} = Rx;

Observable.prototype.distinctUntilKeysChanged = function(keys, compare) {
  return this.distinctUntilChanged((old, current) =>
    // if no value changed,
    // the array will only have true values,
    // includes(false) will be false,
    // convert to oposite (!),
    // returns true;
    // => true = do nothing

    // if any value changed,
    // the array will include some false,
    // includes(false) will be true,
    // convert to oposite (!),
    // returns false;
    // => false = emit

    !keys
    .map(key => compare ? compare(old[key], current[key]) : old[key] === current[key]) // converts to array of boolean
    .includes(false) // if any value changed
  );
};

const stream = new Subject();

stream
  .distinctUntilKeysChanged(['prop', 'prop2'])
  .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 42,
  prop2: 54,
});

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 54,
});

// shouldn't log because neither prop nor prop2 changed
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 54,
});

// should log
stream.next({
  prop: 12346,
  prop2: 5454665654645,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

hope you find it useful